# Arrange different sized divs in a certain pattern

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, responsive

I want to create a Layout like [this](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A382B0EC0E76FBA2!210476&authkey=!AIYgRia0QnLz-Gc&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng) with focus on the "Post"-boxes. 
As you can see, there´re three different kind - a large, a medium and a small one.
The rules I want to create are:

1.) "Large" takes 100% of the width.
2.) "Medium" takes around 60% of the width, is always displayed on the left side
3.) "Small" takes around 40% (considering a margin) of the width, is always displayed on the left side
4.) If the screen size is below a threshold (e.g. 800px) or on mobile, all 3 should be displayed with 100% and below each other.

This is what I got so far

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px; 
}

.large, .medium, .small {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px black;
}

.large {
  width: 100%;
}

.medium {
  min-width: 60%;
  flex: 1 1 0
}

.small {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="large">Div 1</div>
    <div class="medium">Div 2</div>
    <div class="small">Div 3</div>    
    <div class="medium">Div 2</div>
    <div class="small">Div 3</div>  
</div>
```

Problem is, the divs are dynamically added (Wordpress). So if I want to keep this pattern, I´ve to pay attention that I create a "medium" div, right before a "small" div, and then a "medium" div again. If I add two "small" divs right after eacht other, it doesn´t work.
Another problem is, that the height of two divs in the same row are depending from each other. E.g. if I put a bunch of text into "Div 3" and only one sentence into "Div 2", they will be both the same height.

So my question is, is there a better way (preferably without JS) to produce something like my design sketches?

Comment: and if you create for exemple three medium before you create next small, should they all line up to the left?

Comment: @Håkan: Yes, that was the plan, at least if you´re not on mobile.

Comment: So maybe it's better to create two containers, one right and one left, and add the boxes with `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: @Håkan true, that might work, but what happens when I want to add an "large" div? Maybe that wasn't clear from my design sketches, but I also want to make it possible to add a "large" div in the middle or end of the area. In fact it should be possible to add any of these 3 div types anywhere, while the structure should stay the same.

Comment: A "large" div would be added apart from the "right" and "left" divs. Just like it is now. The "large" div will always come apart a bit if you don't have the same amount of "right" and "left" divs

Comment: @Håkan Alright, I´ll give it a try! Thanks for your help!